# GridView and Focus Item

Tags: android-layout, focus

I need a little help.
I have a gridview with some elements.
Touching by finger the screen and selecting the item A, A gets the focus.
I need this:
Moving the finger, without get up the finger from the screen, on another item, A must to loose the focus.

How can I do?

Thanks

I found this solution ... not perfect at 100% but it works nicely

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
                gridview.setSelection(gridview.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                gridview.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```